# Why is my if true/elif/else-code not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

In python, I am trying to make this code accept the user to move forward if he writes "True", and not if he writes "False" for the statement in User_Answer. When I run the code however, I get the "the answer is correct!"-part no matter what I write. The part I am having trouble with starts with "Test_Answer".

Could anyone help me with this?

```
name_list = ["Dean", "Bill", "John"]
enter_club = ["Enter", "enter"]

print ("THE CLUB - by Mads")
print (" ")
print ("""You approach a secret club called \"The club\". The club members are dangerous.
Make sure you tell the guard one of the members names.""")
print ("")
print ("Good evening. Before you are allowed to enter, we need to check if your name is on our list.")

def enter_the_club():
    enter_now = input(" \nPress \"enter\" to enter the club... ")
    if (enter_now in enter_club) == True:
        print (" ")
        print ("But as you enter, you are met with an intelegence test. \n It reads:")

check_name = input("What is your name? ")               
def list_check():
    if (check_name in name_list) == True:
    print("Let me check.. Yes, here you are. Enjoy yourself, %s!" % check_name)
    enter_the_club()
elif check_name.isalpha() == False:
    print("Haha, nice try %s! Let's hear your real name." % check_name)
    list_check()
elif (check_name in name_list) == None:
    print ("You will need to give us your name if you want to come in.")
    list_check()
else:
    print ("I am sorry, but I can not find your name on the list, %s." % check_name)
    print ("Are you sure that's your listed name?")
    list_check()
list_check()

print ("But as you enter, you are met with an intelegence test.")
print (" ")
print ("It reads:")

Test_Answer = True

def IQtest():
User_Answer = input("Is 18/4 % 3 < 18 True or False? ")
if Test_Answer == User_Answer:
    print ("Great, %s, the answer is correct!" % check_name)
else:
    print ("You are not allowed to enter before the answer is correct, %s!" % check_name)
    IQtest()
 IQtest()
```

Comment: Please update this with the code you're actually using, following the posting guidelines.  We cannot reproduce your problem with the given code: this has a syntax error, a semantic error, and no driver program.

Comment: Pasted the whole ting in there now.

Answer (score 0):

True is a boolean constant.  What the user enters will be either "True" or "False", both character strings.  Also, your **elif** condition cannot be true.  What are you trying to do with three decision branches?

Without changing your code too much ... try this?

```
Test_Answer = "True"

def IQtest():
    User_Answer = input("Is 18/4 % 3 < 18 True or False? ")
    if Test_Answer == User_Answer:
        print ("Great, %s, the answer is correct!" % check_name)
    else:
        print ("You are not allowed to enter before the answer is correct, %s!" % check_name)
        IQtest()
```

Note that I've also corrected your "else" syntax.

Also, you have no value for **check_name**; I assume this is a global variable that you've handled elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I am new to Python, so I am just practicing. I implemented the code you gave me, but I still get the same outcome. When I write "False", the it still gives me the string for "True": Check_name was given a value by a input earlier.